# How to show weight in kg and gm on product list page

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute

In product list weight is 0 gm. I set weight in admin panel, but it's weight show in 0 gm..? I set code in

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

code is:

```
<?php  
     $_weight = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getWeight()); 
  if ($_weight < 1)
    $_weightstr = number_format($_weight*1000) . " gm"; 
  else
    $_weightstr = number_format($_weight) . " kg"; echo $_weightstr; ?>
```

Please help...!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the attribute "weight" does not have the option "Used in product listing" set to "Yes"; this can be checked by a simple

```
var_dump($_product->getWeight());
```

in the `list.phtml`; I guess it gives `NULL`.

Change "Used in product listing" to "Yes", reindex & clear the cache to solve this issue.

Comment: thanks....but when i clear the cache and change in product listing nothing happens. still values is null.

Comment: You have to reindex catalog_product_flat to make it work, then.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
<?php  
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());     
$_weight = $this->htmlEscape($_product->getWeight()); 
  if ($_weight < 1)
    $_weightstr = number_format($_weight*1000) . " gm"; 
  else
    $_weightstr = number_format($_weight) . " kg"; 
echo $_weightstr; 
?>
```